# Python module 'spawn'. Module object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, spawn, pexpect

This is my code:

```
import pexpect
import spawn

host = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
userName = 'akshay'
password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

**child = spawn('ssh %s@%s' %(userName, host))**
child.setwinsize(1000,200)
child.expect(['password'], timeout=5)
```

Here I'm trying to SSH into a box using `pexpect` and `spawn` but my Pycharm always returns

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in the bold line

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it completely wrong, first of all spawn is not a module that you need to import

Here is the code :

```
import pexpect

host = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
userName = 'akshay'
password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

child = pexpect.spawn('command here',timeout=5)
child.setwinsize(1000,200)
child.expect('password')
```

Always define timeout in pexpect.spawn, becuase you cannot override it anywhere else